# How group by date ag grid in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I create a ag-grid and I have headerName which is date, time and location.

here's the code

***list.component.ts***

```
columnDefs: any = [{
    headerName: 'Date',
    field: 'date',
    valueFormatter: (data: any) => {
      let date = new Date(data.value);
      const month = date.getMonth;
      return data.value ? month : '';
    },
    rowGroup: true,
    hide: true
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Time',
    field: 'date',
    valueFormatter: (data: any) => {
      return data.value ? (format(data.value, 'hh:mm:ss a')) : '';
    },
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Location',
    field: 'sensor'
  }
]
```

How to group it based on their date.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
columnDefs: any = [{
    headerName: 'Date',
    field: 'date',
    valueFormatter: (data: any) => {
      let date = new Date(data.value);
      const month = date.getMonth;
      return data.value ? month : '';
    },
    rowGroup: true,
    hide: true
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Time',
    field: 'date',
    valueFormatter: (data: any) => {
      return data.value ? (format(data.value, 'hh:mm:ss a')) : '';
    },
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Location',
    field: 'sensor'
  }
]
```

Comment: Error ```function getMonth() { [native code] } (1)```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

at list.component.ts

```
onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent) {
   this.gridApi = params.api;
   this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
   this.gridColumnApi.getColumn('date').setSort('asc');
}
```

It may help you for grouping with sorting by date